# Which heroku buildpack to use for VIPS support on Rails 6.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vips

On Heroku, I would like to use Rails 6.0 with Active Storage and VIPS for fast and low memory image transformation.

I tried following the instructions here https://github.com/janko/image_processing/issues/32, but the build fails:

```
-----> vips app detected
-----> Vendoring binaries
       Fetching wget https://kespry-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/vips/heroku-18/libvips-8.6.2.tgz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile vips app.
 !     Push failed
```

I had these buildpacks in place:

1. heroku-community/apt
2. https://github.com/zoras/heroku-buildpack-libvips

What buildpacks am I recommended to use?

If none exists, how would I go about adding VIPS support for a Heroku buildpack?

Comment: Hello, I help maintain libvips, I'd download the tarball from here: https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/vips-8.8.1.tar.gz

Comment: In case you find it too hard to find or create a buildpack for your needs you could just use Docker to build & deploy to Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker I have only been using it for a few weeks myself, but all good so far and it's fast to deploy.

Comment: Are there any plans for Heroku to support Vips more out-of-the-box like it does ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

This one works well:

https://github.com/brandoncc/heroku-buildpack-vips

Though note that you should bump the libvips version it uses -- it's still on 8.7.1 as I write.